# SharePoint Data Center Migration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

There is a plan to move SharePoint 2013 to different Data Center. We have physical Application and SQL Server (No SQL Alias), Virtual WFE, Office Web App and Workflow Manager server.

While moving it to different Data Center there is plan to do P2V for App And SQL Servers. After move Servers name may remain same, only IPs will change.

What are the best practices to move to diff. Data Center? Can we just clone them or we will have to reinstall SharePoint on new Data Center and configure everything again?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to shut down the farm and associated servers then transport them using the best available method for you. Changing IP addresses will simply require you to update any static DNS records; computer account DNS records will update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have clone them or do P2V migration as part of your process then you must re-run the config wizard in each SP server to join back to the same farm.

If you didn't hard code any ip's while connecting to the farm earlier then it should be straight forward with same alias and DNS names.